# How to remove a file from Path object in Pathlib module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path, pathlib

I have a `Path` Object representing `C:\Users\users\Downloads\img.jpg`. How do I get it so the Path only represents `C:\Users\user\Downloads`? I don't want to delete the file, but rather go back in the Path object itself.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('C:/Users/user/Downloads/img.jpg')
# Want to get path only to C:\Users\user\Downloads
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would utilize the PurePath class within pathlib as follows:

```
from pathlib import PurePath
path = PurePath('C:/Users/user/Downloads/img.jpg')
parent = path.parents[0]
```

This yields: `PureWindowsPath('C:/Users/users/Downloads')`